# Rename sources.list

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In

> /etc/apt/

a have this:

```
apt.conf.d  preferences.d  sources.list  sources.list_bak  sources.list.d  sources.list.save  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg.d
```

I need to remove **sources.list** and rename **sources.list_bak** to **sources.list**

Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$ sudo rm sources.list
$ sudo mv sources.list_bak sources.list
```

Anyway, I would recommend to backup source.list instead of remove it. So, replace the first command with this one:

```
$ sudo mv sources.list sources.list.bak
```